# what is going on in react native example after require?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

I find the following code in [react native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content),

```
 var {
      AppRegistry,
      Image,
      StyleSheet,
      Text,
      View,
    } = React;
```

and it seems like parallel assignment in Python to me. But I can not run it by nodejs:

```
var dict = {a: "19", b: "20"};
var {
    a,
    b
    }
    = dict;

console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

so I am wondering if this syntax is only valid in React native or it is supported by nodejs?

Comment: [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: @zerkms I ask another question, please help me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31900951/why-it-possible-to-use-destructuring-assignment-in-react-native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an ES6 (ES2015) `Destructuring` statement.

https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/#destructuring

React Native uses Babel by default for transformation and `Destructuring` is one of the things enabled by default.