# why it possible to use destructuring assignment in React Native?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, v8, react-native

In the example of [react native tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content), I find syntax which is defined in ECMAScript 2015 (ES6) standard called Destructuring assignment. But as I know, iojs and nodejs do not support this syntax. How can I use it in React Native?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right nodejs and iojs do not support ES6 syntax. But react native:

> As of version 0.5.0, React Native ships with the Babel JavaScript compiler.

[Read more here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/javascript-environment.html#javascript-syntax-transformers)

That means that there is <s>another</s> transpiler ([Babel](http://babeljs.io/)) at work in the React packager. It converts from *ECMAScript 2015 (ES6)* to ES5. This allows you to use the ES6 features like: destructuring, computed property keys, classes, arrow functions, block-scoped variables and more.

If you want to use those features in the React (not Native) app, you will need to include Babel in your project.

---

**Edit:**

There is **no another** transpiler.

> React and React Native have both switched their respective build systems to make use of [Babel](http://babeljs.io/). This replaced [JSTransform](https://github.com/facebook/jstransform), the source transformation tool that we wrote at Facebook.

More in [Deprecating JSTransform and react-tools](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/06/12/deprecating-jstransform-and-react-tools.html)